# Нужно узнать тип (расширение) файла с FTP-сервера

Tags: python, pyqt5, ftp

Делаю `FTP-client` на python и PyQt5. Нужно определять что является папкой(каталогом), а что является файлом((На сервере))? `FTP.mlsd()` не работает(сервер не поддерживает)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fileName

Comment: Не очень понимаю как этим воспользоваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение имени файла из url и его расширения:

```
filename = QUrl("ftp://myserver.com/myfile.txt").fileName()
if filename:
    print(f{"url contains a file {filename}"}) # выведет myfile.txt
    # Получение расширения файла
    print(f'extention={QFileInfo(filename).completeSuffix()}) # выведет txt
else:
    print("url is not a file")
```

Вот такой вариант тоже вернет имя файла:

```
filename = QUrl("ftp://myserver.com/myfile").fileName()
if filename:
    print(f{"url contains a file {filename}"}) # выведет myfile
```

А вот такой в результате выдаст пустую строку:

```
filename = QUrl("ftp://myserver.com/myfile/").fileName()
print(filename) # пустая строка
```

Такие вызовы просто распарсят строку и вернут результат, в частности имя файла.

Для получения ресурсов на ftp-сервере надо воспользоваться классом [QFtp](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qftp.html)
как вот в этом [примере](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/network-qftp.html)

Схематично работу с QFtp можно изобразить так:

```
# Слот. Вызывается для каждого ресурса ftp-сервера
def readFtpResource(urlInfo):
    urlInfo.name() # Вернет url-строку, которую можно отправить в QUrl как описано выше
    urlInfo.isFile() # Сразу скажет является ли ресурс файлом
    urlInfo.isDir() # Является ли ресурс директорией
    # и так далее

ftp = QFtp(<адрес ftp-сервера>)

# Соединяем сигнал обработки ресурсов сервера
ftp.listInfo.connect(readFtpResource)

# Подключение к серваку
ftp->connectToHost(hosturl, port);
```